Advertencia: Argumento no válido proporcionado para foreach()
quiero saber cual fue mi error que no entiendo Advertencia: Argumento no válido proporcionado para foreach() en /var/www/html/prepaLinea/wp-content/themes/PL-SEP-2024/template-parts/campus.php en la línea 19

Buenas, Yadira, bienvenida al sitio. ¿Le has echado un ojo a [tour] y [ask]? Por favor, edita tu pregunta e incluye la línea 19 donde te da ese error (y las circundantes, al menos donde se declaren las variables que estás intentando usar en ese foreach). Comprenderás que es muy, muy difícil que te digamos qué está pasando sin ver esa línea.

Eso es un error de wordpress, en el archivo campus.php linea 19, debería haber algo ahi, pero parece un tema, es una edición tuya o como ?

Debes editar la pregunta y colocar el código en el que está ocurriendo el error. Así a ciegas no sabemos qué está pasando.
